# Calculate the Variance of $\min(N_k,p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, variance

I am trying to compute the variance of a `random variable` $\min(N_k,p)$, where $N_k$ is a random variable and $p$ is a fixed number. I have computed the expectation using the conditional expectation, which is as given below $$\mathbb{E}[\min(N_k, p)] = \mathbb{E}[N_k \mid N_k \leq p] *\mathbb{P}(N_k \leq p)+ \mathbb{E}[\min(N_k, p)\mid N_k > p] * \mathbb{P}(N_k > p).$$ Now, to compute the variance, we need to compute $\mathbb{E}[(\min(N_k,p))^2]$. I don't have any idea how I should proceed to compute this because I don't have access to $\mathbb{P}(\min(N_k,p)=i)$.

Comment: If you don't have any information about the distribution of $N_k$, there is no way you can compute this.

Comment: Use the same formula that you used for  the expectation.

Comment: @user6247850 here, $N_k$'s are discrete random variables. Let's say it is a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can still apply conditional probability, as
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\min(N_k, p)) &= E[(\min(N_k, p))^2] - E[\min(N_k, p)]^2 \\
&= E(N_k^2 | N_k \leq p)P(N_k \leq p) + p^2 P(N_k > p) - \left[ E(N_k | N_k \leq p) P(N_k \leq p) + p P(N_k > p) \right]^2
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: how do we go for this $E(N_k^2 | N_k \leq p)$?

Comment: I'm assuming you know the distribution of $N_k | N_k \leq p$. So then you just use the variance of $N_k | N_k \leq p$.
$$
Var(N_k | N_k \leq p) = E(N_k^2 | N_k \leq p) - E(N_k | N_k \leq p)^2 \implies E(N_k^2 | N_k \leq p) = Var(N_k | N_k \leq p) + E(N_k | N_k \leq p)^2
$$

Comment: Actually, I have access to the distribution of $N_k$ only. I can't compute the variance you mentioned. I have found a way to calculate the expectation, can you verify that is it correct or not?

Comment: \begin{align*}
    E(N_k^2\mid N_k\leq p) &= \sum_{i=1}^n i^2\, P(N_k = i \mid N_k\leq p)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 \;\dfrac{P(N_k = i \cap N_k\leq p)}{P(N_k\leq p)}\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^p i^2 \;\dfrac{P(N_k = i \cap N_k\leq p)}{P(N_k\leq p)}\quad\quad [\text{as $P(N_k = i \cap N_k\leq p)= 0$ for $i>p$.} ]\\&= \sum_{i=0}^p i^2 \;\dfrac{P(N_k = i)}{P(N_k\leq p)}\\&= \dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^p i^2 \,P(N_k = i)}{P(N_k\leq p)}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thus we have $$E(N_k^2 \mid N_k\leq p) * P(N_k\leq p) = \sum_{i=0}^p i^2 \,P(N_k = i) $$ Can I do that? I am a little bit confused.